# Is there a way to retrieve the column names and data types a PL/SQL stored procedure returns?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, plsql, odp.net

I'm working with Entity Framework 6 and ODP.NET, and am importing Stored Procedures into the application's data model. ODP.NET is unable to automatically import stored procedures that use In/Out cursors, and requires that their information be added to the app.config by hand. Worse still, I have over thirty procedures to import, the majority of which make use of In/Out cursors. I've seen that it's possible to [generate config information automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218397/function-imports-for-entity-framework-with-odp-net-managed-driver), but that only seems to work for functions that directly return cursors. (And perhaps with Out cursors too?)

Is there an automated way to retrieve the column names and data types that a stored procedure's cursor returns without manually running down all the information by hand?

An example of how I'm currently importing a procedure in my app.config, sanitized for public consumption:

```
<storedProcedure schema="SCHEMA" name="PACKAGE.PROCEDURENAME">
      <refCursor name="ioCursor">
        <bindInfo mode="InputOutput"/>
        <metadata columnOrdinal="0" columnName="SOMEID" providerType="Int32" allowDBNull="false" nativeDataType="Number"/>            
        <metadata columnOrdinal="1" columnName="SOMEOTHERID" providerType="Int32" allowDBNull="false" nativeDataType="Number"/>
        <metadata columnOrdinal="2" columnName="SOMESTRING" providerType="Varchar2" allowDBNull="false" nativeDataType="Varchar2"/>
      </refCursor>
    </storedProcedure>
```

And how that same procedure appears in its package:

```
PROCEDURE PROCEDURENAME (
    someInputId IN schema.table.column%TYPE
    ,ioCursor IN OUT t_ref_cur
    )

IS

BEGIN
    vProcedureName := 'PROCEDURENAME';
    OPEN ioCursor FOR SELECT a.some_id SOMEID
                            ,a.some_other_id SOMEOTHERID
                            ,b.some_string SOMESTRING
                        FROM  schema.table_a a,
                              schema.table_b b
                        WHERE (selection criteria removed for brevity's sake)
END
```

As you can see, in order to properly fill in the metadata in my app.config, I need to run down the names and types of SOMEID, SOMEOTHERID and SOMESTRING, all three of which could possibly reside in different tables. Some way of pulling in this data automatically would be lovely.

~EDIT~:

### Solved!

Thanks to Christian Shay's answer down below, I ultimately came up with some code that I was able to build a tool around. It does the exact same thing as ODP.NET's "Run Stored Procedure" in the Server Explorer, but it also works with InOut Ref Cursors! Some psuedocode  is below, to show the basic idea of what I wound up doing.

```
using(ContextItem context = new ContextItem())
{
    OracleCommand cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand() as OracleCommand;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "PROCEDURE_NAME_HERE";

    //do the following for all of the input parameters for the stored proc
    OracleDbType paramType = OracleDbType.SomeType;
    OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter("parameterName", paramType);
    param.Value = someValue;

    //or, for cursors
    OracleDbType cursorType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
    ParameterDirection direction = ParameterDirection.SomeCursorDirection;
    OracleParameter cursorParam = new OracleParameter("cursorName", OracleDbType.RefCursor, direction);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(cursorParam);
    if (db.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) 
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Open();  
    }
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
    var table = reader.GetSchemaTable();

    for(int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        /*Now you have access to everything you need for an EF config: 
        Ordinals, column names, provider types, not-null-ness, and native data types*/
    }
}
```

Comment: can you do this getting at the `Schema` Object..?

Comment: @MethodMan Which `Schema` object are you referring to?

Comment: you can do this in SQL Server - you should be able to do / google an equivalent to this in Oracle - http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/0SJK310812-Get-field-name,-data-type-and-size-of-database-table.html

Comment: @MethodMan Ah, I see. I don't need information from a specific table, but rather the columns and data types returned by a cursor from a stored procedure. Question edited to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Please show an example of how you declare and open these cursors.

Comment: SQL Server handles this very differently that Oracle. You can't rely on what you know about SQL Server to do this. Please see the walkthrough I provided in my answer below.

Comment: So, the only thing that caused you to do this extra work is because the Run Stored Procedure doesn't like IN OUT ref cursors? Or is it more than that? Eg if you wrapped your IN OUT procs with ones that simply used OUT, would you have been able to avoid this extra work and simply use Run Stored Procedure wizard? I'm asking because we don't want people to have to think about that config file at all. We want it fully automated.

Comment: Also I would think this would not work, because when you call that SP via the imported function, it should complain that you are not passing IN a REF CURSOR like it expects. Did it work? Are you able to import the function and call it?

Comment: Yep! Sadly, modifying the stored procs isn't an option in this scenario, so I'm forced to live with the IN OUT cursors.

And Re: not handing it a Ref Cursor: that's what the app.config information is for. It informs ODP.NET to use a so-called "implicit Ref Cursor". You can read more about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featImplRefCursor.htm#ODPNT318 . The information is for ODP.NET 11, and so a little out of date, but the concepts still apply.

Comment: No, the app.config metadata is for the output cursor not the input. If you can live without importing the SP as an Entity Function and not converting the rows in the REF CURSOR into entities, you can use the code example I provided in my answer to pull out theOracleCommand, create a REF CURSOR to pass in and call your procs. There's lots of examples out there of calling SPs with IN OUT CURSORS. And you won't need that app.config metadata in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some example code showing how you can call procs from EF code without importing them into your model - essentially you are pulling out the OracleCommand object:

```cs
var ctx = new TestContext();
var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand() as OracleCommand;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "SOMESTOREDPROC";
var p_rc1 = new OracleParameter("p_rc1", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
var p_rc2 = new OracleParameter("p_rc2", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_rc1);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_rc2);

if (ctx.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    ctx.Database.Connection.Open();

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: This led me down the path to a solution, so marking it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could select the metadata like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ALL_ARGUMENTS
  WHERE OWNER = '<your schema name>'
  and object_name = '<your procedure name>'
```

Example output:
[image]

Comment: This is helpful, but what I need is the columns and datatypes returned by the cursor the stored procedures return. I'll edit my question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the metadata by hand. Have a look at the Entity Framework chapter in the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio online help. You use the "Run Stored Procedure" Dialog to do it. It adds the metadata to the config file automatically.

Here is a walkthrough:
https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:106203805408474:::24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PROD_SECTION_GRP_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:10068,,24

See the function import section there.

Note: Only the first REF CURSOR in a stored procedure is used by the Import Function dialog. It becomes the return value of the imported Entity Function by convention. If you have more than one REF CURSOR you will probably need to wrap those SPs with another one.

Also, in your code, you are not using a REF CURSOR. You are using "t_ref_cur". What is that? If it's a User Defined Type this will not work and you will need to at least wrap it to return an actual REF CURSOR since User Defined Types are not supported in this scenario (and the Run Procedure dialog mentioned above won't like it either).

Comment: I'm aware of the "Run Stored Procedure" dialog, and am able to use it for a few of my procs. Unfortunately, for many of them, I get the error `Cannot run procedure or function with the following data types as IN or INOUT parameters: REF CURSOR`.

As for `t_ref_cur`, it's a simple wrapper around a SYS_REFCURSOR. I believe it's defined for backwards compatibility. It has no effect on the "Run Stored Procedure" dialog. For procedures that simply return cursors, the "Run Stored Procedure" dialog handles `t_ref_cur` just fine.

Comment: Why do you have an INOUT REF CURSOR? Do you really pass them in? IN REF CURSORS aren't supported with this scenario. You'll need to wrap the Proc with an OUT only REF CURSOR if you cannot edit the original.

Comment: I added an additional answer that avoids using Import function entirely in case this technique is causing you too many problems.